# Rewrite a with(this) statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, browser

```
new Function(`with(this) { return ${$eval}}`).call({
        moment,
        ...context
});
```

Why can't I use

```
  const that = this;
  const ret = new Function(`with(${that}) { return ${$eval}}`).call({
    moment,
    ...context
  });
```

):

Am I doing something wrong? I need to do this to move code around.

Also if I can rewrite this without with that would be great but not sure how! I am not sure what it's taking from the scope chain as I didn't write the code but it is quite convoluted.

Comment: Can you post more context around the code? What are you trying to do? Right, you should really be avoiding `with`, `eval`, and `new Function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function body you pass to `new Function` is just a string. Instead of trying to interpolate values into the string (which isn’t possible in general), you should declare corresponding paremeters and pass them to the created function:

```
const ret = new Function('that', `with (that) { return ${$eval} }`)({
  moment,
  ...context
});
```

`` new Function('that', `with (that) { return ${$eval} }`) `` represents the function

```
(function (that) {
    with (that) {
        return /* … code from $eval … */
    }
})
```